# adding classes to element

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below,do after method generate new jquery object .If not ,why addClass method is addind class 'foo' on both the *div* as well as *p* element

```
$('<div/>').after('<p></p>').addClass('foo')
  .filter('p').attr('id', 'bar').html('hello')
.end()
.appendTo('body');
```

Comment: please clarify your question,desired input, desired output and provide a jsfiddle with your example.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to understand better, Or Provide jsfiddle example

Comment: Lets see: http://jsfiddle.net/bgL46/. Seems like it does not return a new object.

Comment: @Felix Kling if it dont return than why class foo is added to both div as well as p element?

Comment: @FelixKling - The doco doesn't say so (that I could see), but the behaviour seems to have changed in jQuery 1.9 such that your fiddle doesn't do what the doco says it should. Change the fiddle to v1.8 and it behaves as per the doco...

Comment: @nnnnnn: Interesting... thanks!

Comment: my post is downvoted.??o mara god

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exact scenario is explained in the jQuery API:

"The result is a jQuery set containing a div and a paragraph, in that order."

http://api.jquery.com/after/

Comment: i didn't find it,where is it mentioned.

Comment: @Maizere: http://api.jquery.com/after/#disconnected-dom-nodes Just right before the example you copied.

Comment: @crazylpfan u are too fast.Thank u